# Move MediaWiki without update into new version

Tags: php, mediawiki, mysql, updates, move

**Is it possible to move a MediaWiki (1.9.3) into a new MediaWiki (1.23) on another PC without updating at first?**

As I'm a beginner to Mediawiki/Linux, I don't want to update the old version on the server directly.
And I can't install the old version on the new Server (as Debian Wheezy comes with PHP 5.4 and I failed to downgrade PHP to 5.2).(Mediawiki 1.9 cannot work with PHP 5.3 or higher.)

Can I just do a phpmyadmin database-dump and import it to the new version? What errors do I have to expect? And how to solve them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just dump the database, import it on the new server, copy over LocalSettings.php and the images directory, and run update.php. Though I'm not 100% sure that you could update directly from 1.9.3 to 1.23, so make sure that you keep a backup of the database.